# SpecFlow Configuration

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015, specflow

I've a problem with my SpecFlow configuration. Every time I build my solution I get a pop-up which tell's me : "SpecFlow detected changes in the configuration that might require re-generating the feature files. You disable this popup...ect." I know how to disable

My problem is that all my Feature files create a second version of the class file. So for example I had Commands.feature and two class files; 
 1. Commands.feature.cs 
 2. Commands1.feature.cs

Does anybody know how I can disable this re-generating?

Comment: are you doing something on build which is making a programmatic changes to your tests app.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would suggest is when you have your solution open, do you see duplicate features or steps? If you have a feature and step directory, look under the solution and see if you have a duplicate feature/step listed. I would also check your folders for duplicates in the solution in general.

The regeneration can be turned off in Visual Studio under tools >  options > Specflow > General > Disable re-generate feature file popup.

I keep mine set to false personally but you can turn it off this way. My guess s you have duplicates though.